# Pods do not resolve the domain names of a service through ingress

Tags: dns, kubernetes, minikube

I have a problem that my pods in minikube cluster are not able to see the service through the domain name.

to run my minikube i use the following commands (running on windows 10):
`minikube start --vm-driver hyperv;`
`minikube addons enable kube-dns;`
`minikube addons enable ingress;`

This is my `deployment.yaml`

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    run: hello-world
  name: hello-world
  namespace: default
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: hello-world
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        run: hello-world
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: karthequian/helloworld:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: hello-world
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          protocol: TCP
        resources: {}
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
```

this is the `service.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1                                                             
kind: Service                                                              
metadata:                                                                  
  labels:                                                                  
    run: hello-world                                                       
  name: hello-world                                                        
  namespace: default                                                       
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/services/hello-world                
spec:                                                                      
  ports:                                                                   
  - nodePort: 31595                                                        
    port: 80                                                               
    protocol: TCP                                                          
    targetPort: 80                                                         
  selector:                                                                
    run: hello-world                                                       
  sessionAffinity: None                                                    
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: minikube.local.com                                                           
status:                                                                    
  loadBalancer: {}
```

this is my `ingress.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minikube-local-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: minikube.local.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: hello-world
          servicePort: 80
```

So, if i go inside the `hello-world` pod and from `/bin/bash` will run `curl minikube.local.com` or `nslookup minikube.local.com`.

So how can i make sure that the pods can resolve the DNS name of the service?
I know i can specify `hostAlias` in the deployment definition, but is there an automatic way tht will allow to update the DNS of kubernetes?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I'm not sure I understand why you would want to use service type `ExternalName` and an `Ingress` resource together?

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas , this is just a setup i have right now, it does not have to be `ExternalName`. I want to create a service, and i want any pods withing the same namespace to be able to resolve it by DNS.  

Ex:
I have a hello-world deployment.
I have a service pointing to this deployment.
I want to have a `my-app` deployment that will be able to resolve the `minikube.local.com` to the `hello-world` service without adding this mapping in the hosts file of the `my-app`.

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas does this help ? :)

Comment: Got it, thanks, solution coming up now …

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you want to expose your app on Minikube? I've just tried it using the default `ClusterIP` service type (essentially, removing the `ExternalName` stuff you had) and with [this YAML file](https://gist.github.com/mhausenblas/37e43f1755f2895a2f87719bb4144daa) I can see your service on `https://192.168.99.100` where the Ingress controller lives:

[image: screen shot of hello-world app in browser]

The service now looks like so:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    run: hello-world
  name: hello-world
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    run: hello-world
```

And the ingress is:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minikube-local-ingress
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host:
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: hello-world
          servicePort: 80
```

Note: Within the cluster your service is now available via `hello-world.default` (that's the DNS name assigned by Kubernetes within the cluster) and from the outside you'd need to map, say `hello-world.local` to 192.168.99.100 in your `/etc/hosts` file on your host machine.

Alternatively, if you change the `Ingress` resource to `- host: hello-world.local` then you can (from the host) reach your service using this FQDN like so: `curl -H "Host: hello-world.local" 192.168.99.100`.

Comment: sure, that i understand. So if i deploy a new pod (call it `pod2`), how can i tell the pod to navigate through this specific IP or DNS name? so if `pod2` want to talk to `hello-world`, it would need to access `http://192.168.99.100` and not `hello-world.default` or internal IP address of a service.

Comment: Please read what I wrote. Cluster-internally your service is available via the FQDN `hello-world.default`, that is, if you `curl` it from anywhere within the cluster. I'll also add an alternative DNS solution for outside …